# Is there any way to determine the already filtered values in vba (visual basic) without going through each row of data?

Tags: vba

Is there any way to determine the already filtered values in vba (visual basic) without going through each row of data? I know that each row has a .hidden value which is true if the data is filtered, but is there any way to figure out which data has been filtered without going through each row? This would save me a lot of time.

So, instead of going through each data row, is there any way to determine that, for example, values '4', '5', and '6' have been filtered for column 1 and values '1', '2', and '3' have been filtered for column 2 without going through each row?

Thanks!

Comment: nope, that isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

A little messy, but it works.

The script will print the column ref and the filtered values into the intermediate window for each Column which was an active filter.

You will need to modify it as required.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckFilterSelection()

    Dim SomeSheetName As Worksheet
    Set SomeSheetName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim CurFilter As Filter

    Dim Crite1
    Dim Crite2
    Dim Op
    Dim CurFilterCrit As Variant

    Dim FilterNum As Long

    With SomeSheetName
        If .AutoFilterMode Then

            For FilterNum = 1 To .AutoFilter.Filters.Count

                If .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).On Then
                    'If the Current Filter on a Column has 2 selections then it uses _
                        Criteria1 and Criteria2
                    'If the Current Filter has more than two then it sorts them into an array _
                        in Criteria1
                    If .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Count > 2 Then

                        For Each CurFilterCrit In .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Criteria1

                            Debug.Print "Column " & .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Parent.Range.Column + FilterNum - 1 & _
                                            " Criteria " & CurFilterCrit

                        Next CurFilterCrit

                    ElseIf .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Count = 2 Then

                        Debug.Print "Column " & .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Parent.Range.Column + FilterNum - 1 & _
                                        " Criteria " & .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Criteria1
                        Debug.Print "Column " & .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Parent.Range.Column + FilterNum - 1 & _
                                        " Criteria " & .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Criteria2

                    ElseIf .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Count = 1 Then

                        Debug.Print "Column " & .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Parent.Range.Column + FilterNum - 1 & _
                                        " Criteria " & .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Criteria1
                    End If


                End If
            Next FilterNum
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way to determine the number of CurFilterCrit In .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Criteria1? I was trying to use  .AutoFilter.Filters(FilterNum).Criteria1.Count, but this did not work.

Comment: @JSmith its not really easy to capture all the info easily so I had to work around. What is your purpose of needing it? I think I did a pretty stellar job is answer your question.